# How to use two incompartible classes with same full name?

Tags: java, spring, classloader

A problem: My application uses two libraries which use incompatible versions of a third library. Does someone know any method for classes isolation?

I have heard about class loaders, but I do not understand, how they could help - if we will load one version of class, we cannot load another - class is already loaded?

I also thinking about Spring, but do not know if it provides such isolation.

Comment: I take it these two classes are not in separate namespaces?

Comment: I do not understand what "namespace" mean in context of Java. A package name? Let them be in different packages if it is important.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I meant packages.  And also, I misread your question, so I don't think it's relevant!

Comment: Have you reported this issue to the authors of the library which uses the old version? Might be worth doing so. This is a really nasty situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if we will load one version of class, we cannot load another - class
>   is already loaded?

Not true. The class loader is considered part of the class's identity. If it's loaded by a different classloader, it's considered a different class.

Comment: Does it mean that we can handle classes as a java Objects? For example, out them into array or list, or create more then one instance?

Comment: @Nulldevice Classes can only be instantiated from bytecode, by classloaders. However, yes, they are objects, and can be put in arrays or lists. I think only ClassLoaders would need to do such things.

Answer (score 2):

ClassLoaders are basically the elements that gives meaning to classes in the JVM. They form a hierarchy for wich the root lies in the JVM and loads java classes. The ApplicationClassLoader is the first ClassLoader you have to consider, as it loads all the classes of your application.

When a class is loaded, all its references to other classes are resolved and theses classes are loaded. The JVM by default provides a system where classloaders ask their parent first to see if they have already loaded a class. If not, they search in their classpath

Two classes can be isolated if they live in 2 different classloader, and not in the app classloader. It's not difficult to do. You only have to create a classloader (like URLClassLoader) while specifying its parent and its classpath(the place where the bytecode is)

then, you tell him to load a class. It will ask its parent, and if the class is not loaded yet, it will search its classpath and load it. If you create another classloader attached to the same parent, the classes loaded by the first will never be seen by the seconds as they are siblings. And the second can loads a class with the same name without any problem

That's quite a good isolation

App Servers use another form of delegation to have a frank isolation between applications. they redefine a classloader extending, for example, URLClassLoader and reverse the delegation process by starting to search for classes in their classpath first, then ask to the parent

Answer (score -1):

If at least one of the libraries is open source, and the library they depend on is open source, no need for messing about with classloaders. Just bulk rename all the packages in one of the versions of the library being depended on, making sure to also change all code which refers to those packages. Hey presto - no name clashes. This is what Sun actually did for the JDK, when they included Xerces and Xalan behind the scenes.

Comment: What if I say that it is a project which developed by ~50 software engineers? I do not want to be responsible for bug fixing of thousands of lines of code. It is not so easy to change versions of some libraries, even open sourced.

Comment: You can just write a script which does the necessary renamings, and run that script on every new version that is released. Watch out for `Class.forName`, but it should be relatively simple.

Comment: Sir, it has tens of thousands lines of code - are you joking?

Comment: No, I'm not joking. A script does not care how many lines of code it has to work with.

Comment: I do not mean script - I mean many libraries, even open source have no back compatibility, and moving to new version can have side effects, like missed class, or modified method signature. So, such method is possible, but it can be difficult enough.

Comment: This answer should not be downvoted because it has been *successfully used to solve precisely this problem, in the JDK, as stated in the answer*. I am not suggesting moving to new versions. I am saying *if and when* you want to move to new versions, you can re-run the script.